# How do I get my data from my DB as a variable?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am using Angular, Spring Boot and Mongo DB.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.LoginService.getLoginList().subscribe(data => {

      this.login = data;

      alert(JSON.stringify(data));


    });
```

When I put an alert  in typescript, I get this on my alert,

`[{"username":"user123","pass":"pass@123"}]`

And if I don't Stringify it I get,

[object Object]

I have try to use the variable as,

```
this.login.username
login.username
data.username
```

but nothing seems to work and I keep getting

`undefined`

on my alert.

How do I save the data I am getting in JSON format to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that your LoginService is more or less looking like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    
    constructor() { }
    
    private loginDataSource = new Subject<any>();
    loginDataService$ = this.loginDataSource.asObservable();

    getLoginList(userData) {
        this.loginDataSource.next({
            data: userData
        });
    }
}
```

In this service I declare the loginDataSource as a RxJs Subject. Then I upgraded your getLoginList() method to have a userData as parameter. Inside the method I used the .next() to loginDataSource to basically return whatever the latest userData there is. With this approach you will get the most recent login data

Answer (score 0):

The data you have appears to be an array, so you'll need to get an element from that array to access its fields. `data[0]` would get the first element, but it's important to find out why this is an array in the first place.

Comment: I am using an Observable to get data from the database.

this.LoginService.getLoginList().subscribe(data => {
      this.login = data;
      alert(data[0]);
    });

this returns as undefined again.